# Interesting problems using group/representation theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, recreational-mathematics, big-list

I've been going through this representation theory [lecture notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~serganov/math252/notes1.pdf), and I've found the ''hungry knights'' problem very interesting.
Do you know any interesting problems similar to that one?

To define ''similar'': problems which have a recreational, puzzle-like taste and you can solve them using representation theory/group theory.
One example I know is [this series](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/gila-i-group-actions-and-equivalence-relations/) of blog posts by Qiaochu Yuan applying group theory to few basic combinatorial questions about colorings.

Answer (score 4):

A similar one is a Russian Olympiad problem about 7 dwarfs sitting around a table drinking wine. Each of them have a wine cup in front of them. In turn, they split the wine in their glass into 6 equal portions and distribute it out. After a round of distribution, they found that they have the same amount of wine as at the start. How much wine did each dwarf have?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a paper: [A Theorem about Primes Proved on a Chessboard](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689726). It is

> "An elementary treatment of a class of solutions to the $n$-queens problem leads to a proof of Fermat's theorem on primes which are sums of two squares."

It also uses the chessboard to provide a specific geometrical setting for illustrating and  interpreting abstract concepts usually first encountered in an introductory abstract algebra course, such as cyclic group, subgraph, and coset.